# C++11esque signature of a function computing a scalar of a collection of values

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, iterator

Up to now, I would have guessed that

```
double mean(ConstIterator startIt, ConstIterator endIt);
```

is a decent signature for a function computing the mean of a collection of values stored in an std collection.

But with C++11, we have both lamdas and `for val : Col`.

What is a best practice signature for such a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until we get ranges, nothing much will change in terms of functions taking collections of values.

However, unless the function is specific for certain types, usually this sort of thing is implemented generically:

```
template<typename Iterator, typename Sentinel>
auto mean(Iterator begin, Sentinel end) { // C++14 deduced return type
  // ...
}
```